# In CakePHP, is there an Inflector method to transform an UpperCamelCase to a lowerCamelCase format?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I read the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) doc, and it says : `In your controller, set a camelCase plural variable` ... to show belongsTo or habtm (hasAndBelongsToMany) relationship data, with a form select tag.

Is there a way to do it with [Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) methods or I should set a [rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration) to get that transformation ?

Comment: Wouldnt a simple lcfirst() do the trick?

Comment: Yes. See answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use:

```
    Inflector::variable($underscored)
    Input: apples, user_result, people_people
    Output: apples, userResult, peoplePeople
```

This is right from Cake Docs - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html

*** Edited ***

To be more specific for this solution:

```
     Inflector::pluralize(Inflector::variable($this->modelClass));
```

Comment: To be more specific : Inflector::pluralize( Inflector::variable($this->modelClass) ) will do what I was looking for.

Comment: I added your changes to the answer @EricLavoie Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found also a way using php [lcfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) string function and [Inflector::pluralize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html). Example :

```
Inflector::pluralize( lcfirst($this->modelClass) )
```